# Summing ; delimited values in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a column titled priclmdetailli55 in a file which can be blank, have one value or can be two value separated by a semicolon. In the case that the numbers are separated by a semicolon I would like the values summed.

This is what I have been trying to use.

```
 var str = priclmdetailli55;
        var1 = str.substring(0,str.indexOf(";") );
        var2 = str.substring(str.indexOf(";") + 1, str.length + 1);

        var1 = var1.replace(",", "");
        var2 = var2.replace(",", "");


        var var3 = parseint(var1) + parseint(var2); 

{var var3}
```

However, the column appears blank when this code is applied. Any tips or thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: `var sum = str.split(';').reduce( (a,b) => (+a)+(+b)));`

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax looks slightly wrong. So what I would do if there were some `,` in the numbers like `10,000` or so, I would use a simple regex.

Flicking from [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo), I would write the following code that works for numbers with and without commas.

```js
var str = "10;15;20";
var sum = str.split(';').reduce((a, b) => parseInt(("" + a).replace(/,/g , "")) + parseInt(("" + b).replace(/,/g , "")));
console.log(sum);

str = "10,200;15,500;20,100";
sum = str.split(';').reduce((a, b) => parseInt(("" + a).replace(/,/g , "")) + parseInt(("" + b).replace(/,/g , "")));
console.log(sum);
```

The above code will do the function in the following method:

1. Splits the string by `;`.
2. Removes the `,` from each number.
3. Adds using an [accumulator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Parameters).
4. Returns the sum of numbers.